# Why are there strips of faces that are a different color from the Base Color?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, shaders, color

My model has these small parts of it that are miscolored, and I don't know why. I think it might be related to the lighting. Does anyone know why this is, or what causes it? I'm new to Blender, and I need some help.[image: The Model.]

Comment: you seem to have duplicate vertices, can you try edit mode > mesh > merge > by distance

Comment: Could you share your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: In the Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode, make sure that Opaque is selected. It may also be the normal map, make sure that the Image Texture is set to Color Space > Non-Color